# Difference between Palpable vs tangible

Tags: word-choice

When would I use one over the other?

Found this comparison, which did not clarify it for me:

https://wikidiff.com/palpable/tangible

Comment: Both words have a very similar meaning; I don't think there is any context in which you _should_ use one rather than the other.

Comment: Wikidiff is a really bad quality crowdsourced site.

Comment: My sense is that "palpable" is the less common word, and is used mainly in a metaphorical sense ("almost touchable"), particularly of intense emotions (joy, fear, etc). "Tangible" is more likely to be used literally (e.g. you talk about "tangible controls" meaning controls that let you manipulate things with touch, and a "tangible asset"). But it's definitely a case of different words being used more commonly in different contexts, based on different models and traditions (e.g. you get allusions to "a palpable hit" from Shakespeare), so if you have a particular context you should say.

Comment: ... though 'Can Social Media be a Tangible Tool for Market Research?' [[portma.com](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22a+tangible%22&ei=0-80YKDjEYupgAaXqIKgCQ&start=20&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwjgmMeD_P_uAhWLFMAKHReUAJQ4ChDy0wN6BAgEEDc&biw=1314&bih=734)] shows a metaphorical usage where 'palpable' wouldn't work. I think this is because 'tangible tool' is the metaphor, within which concreteness has to be maintained. 'Tangible' is on occasion replaceable by 'hands-on'.

Comment: A thesaurus will make this clear. There are meanings for one that don't really apply to the other. In particular, tangible has more meanings, and palpable has a medical meaning that tangible does not have.